# apply vectorized function on unique values and expand

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to speed up the calculation of `dt[,col2:=f(col1)]`
by running `f` only on distinct values of `col1`. `dt` is a data table and `f` returns vectors of the same length as the input.

Is there any nicer way than

```
dt[, id:=.GRP, by=.(col1)]
tmp <- dt[,.(col1=col1[1]), by=.(id)][,col2:=f(col1)]
dt[, col2:=tmp$col2[match(id, tmp$id)]][,id:=NULL]


#for example
#dt<-data.table(col1=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T))
#f<-function(x) {print(x); paste("a",x)}
```

Comment: please use `set.seed` along with `sample`.

Comment: `fres <- dt[ , lapply( unique(col1), f )]` ?

Comment: I am interested in cases where it is faster to use vectorized `f ` and the result should be `dt` with one column `col2` added.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `dt[, col2 := f(col1[1]), by = col1]`. Obviously, the group-by operation has some performance overhead as have the repeated calls to the closure `f`. Thus, you will only improve performance with this strategy if `f`'s vectorization is slow (e.g., there is a loop internally) and you have large groups of duplicated values. I suggest doing some benchmarks.